# How to specify color using a VARIANT

Tags: c++, internet-explorer

I need to set the color of an HTML element, I've managed to get a reference to the style but I now need to pass a `VARIANT` to the `put_color` method and I can't find information regarding how you construct a variant.

How would I go about specifying the color `#ffaaaa` for the `put_color` call?

```
CComPtr<IHTMLStyle> spStyle = htmlElement->get_style;
spStyle->put_color(what_goes_here?);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the colour string in a [`BSTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069.aspx) value, which is one of the types accepted by a [`VARIANT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221627.aspx):

```
VARIANT color;
color.vt = VT_BSTR;
color.bstrVal = SysAllocString(TEXT("#ffaaaa"));
spStyle->put_color(color);
VariantClear(&color);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, you're an absolute life saver. It's a long time since I've coded in c++, this does seem an incredibly complicated way to specify a color. Think it would have taken quite a while to get there.

Comment: @opsb: You're welcome. You'll come across the `VARIANT` type in a lot of COM interfaces, because it is easier for the system to pass around this single wrapper type rather than have different argument types for each function.

Comment: Don't forget to free the memory you allocate with `SysAllocString`.  `VariantClear` will take care of this for you.